# How to show titles for UIToolBar items

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

Is there a standard way to enable showing title to toolbar items in `UIToolBar`? `UIBarButtonItem` has properties for both image and title, but when I set them, only image appears. Is there a way to present also a title (similarly to standard Phone application in iOS)?

My code:

```
let settings = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settingsEmpty").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
settings.title = "Settings"
toolbarItems = [settings]
```

Comment: What standard iOS application do you see both a title and image on a toolbar? Are you sure you are not confusing the toolbar with a tab bar?

Comment: well.. yeah.. you are right, I want a toolbar that looks like a toolbar

Comment: Huh? You want a toolbar that looks like a toolbar? Do you mean you want a toolbar that looks like a tab bar?

Comment: toolbar looking like a tabbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not available in the standard control, you can only show image or title. You must make a custom control that does that - for the `UIBarButtonItem` you can set the `customView` (and as toolbar might turn out to be too small you might need to customize its height too). The purpose of the title is to be shown if there is no image, or to be read to users that use VoiceOver to navigate the app.